# javascript object/array undefined vs empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a Coldfusion page that makes an Ajax call to a cffunction that returns a query.

JS:

```
function showPlaced(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cfc/basic.cfc?method=GetCandidatePlacedJson',
        data: 'searchNum=' + <cfoutput>#searchnum#</cfoutput>,
        dataType:'json',
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(response2, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log (response2);
            console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(response2.DATA));
            if (typeof response2.DATA === undefined) {
                $("#placeddiv").hide();
            } else {
                if ((response2.DATA[0][0] != '') && (response2.DATA[0][13] == '')) {
                    //alert(response2.DATA[0][0]);
                    $('#Date_Accepted').val(response2.DATA[0][9]) // date accepted
                    $('#Start_DateDspOnly').val(response2.DATA[0][10]) // start date
                    $('#Start_Salary').val(response2.DATA[0][11]) // starting salary
                    $('#Additional_compensation').val(response2.DATA[0][12]) // additional compensation
                    $('#placedcandidatespan').html(response2.DATA[0][0]) // candidate name
                    $('#utitlespan').html(response2.DATA[0][3]) // candidate Title
                    $('#worknumberspan').html(FormatPhoneNumberPlaced(response2.DATA[0][1])) // work phone
                    $('#homenumberspan').html(FormatPhoneNumberPlaced(response2.DATA[0][2])) // home phone
                    $("#placeddiv").show();
                } else {
                    $("#placeddiv").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

ColdFusion:

```
<cffunction name="GetCandidatePlacedJson" output="false" access="remote" returntype="query" returnformat="json">
    <cfargument name="searchNum" required="Yes" type="string" default="">
    <cfset var queryResults="">
        <cfquery name="queryIResults" datasource="#request.dsn#" dbtype="ODBC">
            SELECT ui.firstname + ' ' + ui.lastname as PlacedName,ui.Work_Phone,Home_Phone, usm.description as Utitle,ui.title_number,csi.gone,csi.search_number
            ,csi.individual_number, csi.date_of_placement, cscc.accepteddate, cscc.startdate, cscc.startsalary, cscc.AdditionalCompensation, cscc.offerturneddown
            FROM client_searches_individuals as csi
            LEFT JOIN users_info as ui ON csi.individual_number = ui.id
            Left join users_skill_mask as usm on usm.skill_number = 1 and usm.line_number = UI.title_number
            Left Join client_searches_candidate_checklist as cscc on cscc.individual_number=csi.individual_number and cscc.search_number = csi.search_number
            WHERE csi.search_number = #val(arguments.searchNum)# AND cscc.accepteddate > '' AND isnull(cscc.offerturneddown, '') = ''
        </cfquery>
    <cfreturn queryIResults>
</cffunction>
```

When the function returns no rows, the console log shows;

```
Object { COLUMNS: Array[14], DATA: Array[0] }
```

And the error;

```
TypeError: response2.DATA[0] is undefined
```

When the function returns a row, the console log shows;

```
Object { COLUMNS: Array[14], DATA: Array[1] }
```

And the elements are populated.

I've tried jQuery `$.isEmptyObject()` but it's not reliable.  At least in this scenario. The hide/show `div` shows the user whether a candidate has been placed or not.

I'm running Coldfusion v10 64 bit.

Comment: I suggest changing the returntype of your function to something that javascript can accept.  Then add more code to your function to produce that format.  Not related to your question, but the variable you "var" has a different name than the one you use.  Also, query parameters are better than val() in sql strings.

Comment: All good suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the length of the array object to see whether it has any data like

```
if (!response2.DATA || !response2.DATA.length) {
  $("#placeddiv").hide();
} else {

}
```

Also, [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator returns a string value, so if the value of `respose.DATA` is undefined, then `typeof response.DATA` will be `'undefined'`

Comment: if (!response2.DATA || !response2.DATA.length) {  works just fine.